# Average Rainfall Calculator

Tags: python, average

This is the updated program I have written so far:

```
# This program averages rainfall per month.  It asks the user for the number
# of years.  It will then display the number of months, the total inches of
# rainfaill, and the average rainfall per month for the entire period.

# Get the number of years.

total_years = int(input('Enter the amount of years: '))

# Get the amount of rainfall for each month of each year.

for years in range(total_years):
    # Initialize the accumulator.
    total = 0.0
    print('Year', years + 1)
    print('----------------')
    for month in ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'):
        inches = float(input(month))
        total += inches

total_inches = total

total_month = total_years * 12

average_inches = total / total_month



        # Display the average.
print('The total number of months is: ', total_month)
print('The total inches of rainfall is: ', total_inches)
print('The average rainfall per month for the entire period is: ', average_inches)

print()
```

This is the new error message I am getting when attempting to test the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Programming Concepts/Homework 2/Chapter
5/Average Rainfall maybe.py", line 23, in <module>
average_inches = total / month
TypeError: unspupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
```

Any ideas on how to fix/improve this code?

Now, all I need to fix is my calculations.  I think they are wrong (lines 23-27).

Comment: Dont supply input with two arguments, remove the `, month` and in the passed string add the itterated month

Comment: `input('Enter the inches measured in month %s'% month)`

Comment: Don't use input. use raw_input.

Comment: @ColinDunklau Only in Python 2. In Python 3 (which this appears to be), you should use `input`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages references where the error occurred:

```
average_inches = total / month
```

Specifically,

```
TypeError: unspupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
```

..is saying it cannot divide a float (`total`) by a string (`month`).

`month` is the completely wrong thing to be dividing by (it's just a string containing "January" or whatever).. You want to divide by the [number of months](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len)

As a hint, I'd suggest start by doing:

```
ALL_MONTHS = ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'):
```

Then change your loop to:

```
for month in ALL_MONTHS:
```

That way you can refer to `ALL_MONTHS` again later...

Comment: I just did a double take. Since the error message has been edited, my answer no longer addresses the question :P, anyway +1.